# OSM - Popup not visible while clicking on marker

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, openstreetmap

OSM Popup does not showed up while clicking on marker.
I have tried click event on marker. Does it works?
Suggest me how do i show popup on marker while clicking on it.

`JS` Code i have tried

```
var newlonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 78.447876 ,17.371610 )
.transform( new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
    map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    );
var zoom=9;
var newmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(newmarkers);
newmarkers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(newlonLat));
map.setCenter (newlonLat, zoom);

newmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );

newmarkers.events.register('mouseover', newmarkers, function(evt) {
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",
    newlonLat,
    new OpenLayers.Size(200,50),
    "Location", 
    true);
    map.addPopup(popup);
});

newmarkers.events.register('mouseout', newmarkers, function(evt) {
    popup.hide();
});

map.addLayer(newmarkers);
newmarkers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(Tlon,Tlat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection),icon));
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the OpenLayers API, the [Marker layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Markers-js.html) itself does not have any feature-selection handling. [But Vector Layers does](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html). However, the marker itself can handle mouse events too.

Your code does not work, because you tried to register the 'mouseover' event on the layer instead of the marker.

So either you add the event handler directly to your marker:

```
myMarker.events.register('mousedown', myMarker, function(evt) { alert("this is Sparta! " + this.icon.url); OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt); });
```

OR use an vector layer for your markers, [as seen in this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-marker-popup.html)

OR use a Layer.Text ([Layer.Text sample](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/markersTextLayer.html))